# Prove that $p ◦ p = p$. (Representing a Linear Transformation as a Matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis, projection-matrices

Let $B = (1, X, X^2)$ be an ordered basis for $\mathbb{R}_2[X]$ and $p ∈ \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}_2[X])$ be the linear map defined by $p(1) = \frac{1}{3}(2 − X − X^2)$, $p(X) = \frac{1}{3}(−1 + 2X − X^2)$ and  $p(X^2) = \frac{1}{3} (−1 − X + 2X^2)$.

By definition of the task, I found that $A = M_B(p)$

Compute $A^2$. Prove that $p ◦ p = p$.

\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} \\
    -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} \\
    -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} &\frac{2}{3} \\
\end{bmatrix}

I computed the multiplication and it appears that $A^2$ = $A$.  How should I prove it?

Comment: Does $M_B(p)$ mean the matrix of $p$ with respect to the basis $B$?

Comment: Sure, that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is the matrix corresponding to the linear operator $p$, then $p(v)=A\cdot v\ \forall v\in\Bbb R_2[X]$.

$\implies(p\circ p)(v)=p(p(v))=A\cdot(p(v))=A\cdot(Av)=(A\cdot A)v=A^2\cdot v$

This means the matrix corresponding to the linear operator $p\circ p$ is $A^2$. Since $A^2=A$, the matrices corresponding to $p$ and $p\circ p$ are identical, which means $p=p\circ p$.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful!

Comment: You're welcome.